# Jinja template code showing as text instead of working as intended

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I´m currently using Google Application Engine with Python as programming language and Jinja for the templates. The thing is that Jinja code doesn´t work, it just shows up on the webpage as text (like if it was inside a

tag). I´m using Pycharm and I´ve already added Jinja as my template languaje.

main.py

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'user': "User",
            'tuits': {"User", "Tweets this", "time"}
        }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template("index.html")
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> TWITTER </title>
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TUiter</h1>
        <a href="/postTuit">Publicar TUit</a>
        <div>
            {% if tuits.count() > 0 %}
                {% for tuit in tuits %}
                <div>
                    <p>{{ tuit.user }}</p>
                    <p>{{ tuit.message }}</p>
                    <p>{{ tuit.time }}</p>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.yaml

```
application: supercoolname
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /
  static_files: templates/index.html
  upload: index\.html

- url: /postTuit
  static_files: templates/postTuit.html
  upload: postTuit\.html

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: You told the app engine to serve `templates/index.html` verbatim in your `url: /` directive.

Comment: so should I rename the file to something else? It´s the first time I´m using Jinja and even though I checked documentation and everything I´m a bit lost.

Comment: No, I haven't tested this myself but I believe you should simply change the action to `script: main.app`.

Comment: remove these lines in your app.yaml: - url: /
  static_files: templates/index.html
  upload: index\.html. They will present a static version of your index html. And your route .* below for main.app will never work.

Comment: @voscausa Thanks a lot, it worked! on the example I was following they had the exact same app.yaml as I did, so I never thought it could came from that, thank you again!

Comment: Your welcome. I think you should move to GAE with Python 3 and flask. Google is moving away from the Python 27 webapp2 GAE standard environment,

Comment: @voscausa I woudl, but this is a college assingment. The thing is my teacher would rather kill himself than update his material so we can program on something that is actually useful when we finish the degree :/